# Image Rollovers with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing this for my assignment which is due next week. 
Our instructor wanted us to create image rollovers. I already created one but it won't work.
Here's my code:

```
<script>
function turnSwitchOn(img) {
    buttonImg="lab11-1switchon.jpg"
    document.getElementById(lightswitch).src=buttonImg
}
function turnSwitchOff(img) {
    buttonImg="lab11-1switchoff.jpg"
    document.getElementById(lightswitch).src=buttonImg
}
</script>
```

and here's the img:

```
<img src="lab11-1switchoff.jpg" alt="light switch" id="lightswitch" onMouseOver="turnSwitchOn()" onMouseOut="turnSwitchOff()" />
```

The picture on my Website won't change to the one I put in the Javascript code, why is that?

Comment: You are referencing an undefined variable lightswitch when you want to reference the string "lightswitch" while using the getElementById function. Try putting (lightswitch) to be ("lightswitch").  There may be other problems, but that is first fix.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It worked. The book we use didn't have the quotation marks in it though.

Comment: Sounds like that book sucks

Comment: Use online resources they'll always be more up to date than a textbook

Comment: The book is kinda hard to understand. But this HTML course will be completed by the second week of December.

Answer (score 1):

Your Id's need to be in quotes

```
function turnSwitchOn(img) {
    buttonImg="lab11-1switchon.jpg"
    document.getElementById("lightswitch").src=buttonImg
}
function turnSwitchOff(img) {
    buttonImg="lab11-1switchoff.jpg"
    document.getElementById("lightswitch").src=buttonImg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fix for making sure to call getElementById with a string ("lightswitch"), you could get a little nicer and not even have to lookup the image by id at all if you pass `this` into the function:

```
<script>
function turnSwitchOn(img) {
    img.src="lab11-1switchon.jpg"
}
function turnSwitchOff(img) {
    img.src="lab11-1switchoff.jpg"
}
</script>

<img src="lab11-1switchoff.jpg" alt="light switch" id="lightswitch" onMouseOver="turnSwitchOn(this)" onMouseOut="turnSwitchOff(this)" />
```